# Сделать все кнопки маленькими (btn-small)

Tags: bootstrap

Как сделать так, чтобы все кнопки внутри определенной панели (не только дети, но и все потомки), были маленькими (как `btn-small`)?

Думал, что тег `small` поможет, - не помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прописать каждой кнопке класс явно.

Лень двигатель прогресса? Тогда что-то типа `$('#id_панельки .btn').addClass('btn-small');`